# Why do nitrogen-containing organic compounds give N2 as the combustion product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, combustion, reduction-potential, pnictogen

My teacher gave the explanation stating that consider that first the nitrogen in lower state is oxidised to $\ce{N2}$ and then the further oxidation would stop as the $\ce{N-N}$ bond energy of $\ce{N2}$ is very high and can't be overcome under normal conditions.

But my doubt is can't the nascent nitrogen (formed during the formation of $\ce{N2})$ react further with $\ce{O2}$ and get oxidised to some higher oxides like $\ce{NO2}$ or $\ce{N2O}?$

The Latimer diagram shows that it is possible for oxygen to oxidise the nitrogen to higher states:

[image: Latimer diagram Of nitrogen]

Comment: I don't think they do. If you search "combustion products of triethylamine" for example you will find phrases such as "Combustion products include: carbon dioxide (CO2), nitrogen oxides (NOx), other pyrolysis products typical of burning organic material."

Comment: Additionally, NOx is created during gas engine combustion from aerial N2, as equilibrium N2 + O2 <=> 2 NO is not so strongly shifted to the left at high temperatures.

Comment: Side note: "*nascent nitrogen*" is an obsolete term used to explain high reactivity in certain cases long time ago. These days, it's more appropriate to call it by what it really is: atomic nitrogen.

Comment: What else could it be? All nitrogen oxides are endothermic. I mean, yeah, they would form to some tiny extent, but not as the major product.

Comment: @govind Note that atomic nitrogen would help with kinetics. But it must fight the thermodynamics in the first place. Molecular nitrogen is thermodynamically highly preferred, forming nitrogen oxides just as minor compounds.

Comment: @Poutnik The electrode potential for conversion of NH4+ to N2O4 and NO to N2O4 according to the Latimer diagram are -0.89V and -1.033V. Also the conversion of NO to NO2 is spontaneous in atmospheric oxygen. so thermodynamics might not be the appropriate reason for molecular nitrogen being the major product.

Comment: is there something special for this rxn https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0021961483901271

Comment: What is important is the standard electrode potential, or the equivalent standard reaction Gibbs energy for conversions of particular nitrogen species to $\ce{N2}$. Like jumping from a tree branch to another branch can produce energy, but molecular nitrogen is on the ground.

Comment: @andselisk Converted my (deleted) comment into a question: [Why is the term “nascent nitrogen” still used in metallurgical industries?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155582/why-is-the-term-nascent-nitrogen-still-used-in-metallurgical-industries)

Comment: @Govind not only do they give elemental nitrogen, they do give all sorts of nitrogen oxides. See these papers for more info.: https://pubs.rsc.org/En/content/articlelanding/1947/an/an9477200142/unauth... https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0926860X02000133 ... https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0026265X66900531